# Acceleration with DoParallel in R not working in my code

Tags: r, doparallel

```
# approximation of PI using random numbers and large iterations  
# the surface of a square of one by one = 1
# the program will generate random numbers between 0 and 1
# these are x and y as coordinates, plotting spots witin the 1 by 1 square
# a circle within that square has a (R)radius of 0.5 
# all spots will land within the square, but not all spots will land within the circle
# the surface of the circle within the square is PI multiplied by R square, 
# so effectively 0.25 pi
# iterations is the number of random spots
# counter counts the number of spots within the inner circle
# counter / iterations = 0.25 PI /1
# PI = 4 multiplied by (counter / iterations)



# single core

# clean all
rm(list=ls())

# to easily set the number of iterations
power10=5

iterations <- 10^power10
start <- proc.time()
counter <- 0
for (i in 1:iterations) {
  x <- runif(1)
  y <- runif(1)
  xd <- x-0.5
  yd <- y-0.5
  xsqr <- xd*xd
  ysqr <-yd*yd
  incircle <- xsqr+ysqr
  if (incircle<0.25) counter <- counter +1
}


end <- proc.time()
time_singlecore <- (end - start)[3]
print("The execution time was : ")
time_singlecore
PiApprox <- (counter/iterations)*4
print("Approximation of PI : " )
PiApprox





#parallel version
# clean all
rm(list=ls())

library(doParallel)  
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# to easily set the number of iterations
power10=5

iterations <- 10^power10
start <- proc.time()
counter_p <- 0
total_p <- foreach (i = 1:iterations, .combine= "+" ) %dopar% {
  x <- runif(1)
  y <- runif(1)
  xd <- x-0.5
  yd <- y-0.5
  xsqr <- xd*xd
  ysqr <- yd*yd
  incircle <- xsqr+ysqr
  (incircle<0.25) 
}


end <- proc.time()
time_parallel <- (end - start)[3]
print("The execution time in paralel mode was : ")
print(time_parallel)
PiApprox_p <- (total_p/iterations)*4
print("Approximation of PI : ")
PiApprox_p


stopCluster(cl)`
```

I have played with example code and doParallel and get the idea high level.
Yet I am probably making a large mistake as my own code slows down 100x when I use doparallel.
I would expect a speed up certainly when numbers increase.(overhead of map and reduce effect should then be less)
No doubt a silly beginners mistake but I can not find it myself.
Thanks for the help

Comment: On a side note (not related to `doParallel`), this problem can be very efficiently solved without any loops making use of `R's` built in vectorization capabilities: 
`PiApprox <- sum(((runif(iterations) - .5) ^ 2 + (runif(iterations) - .5) ^ 2) < .25) / iterations * 4
`

Comment: Thanks for the compact and powerful rewrite suggestion and emphasizing the vectorization capabilities. I have not yet reached the level code like this myself, but just enough basic knowledge to learn from it. so again thanks! 
Still curious to understand the mall performance of the parallelization of this code. It should be embarrassing parallel but maybe the calculation is so simple that any form of overhead destroys the performance? and parallelization only works with large computations..?

Comment: My assumption: the expensive part here‘s the memory allocation, while the operations themselves are cheap. With parallelization you need to do even more memory allocation and hence it becomes notably slower. But this is a mere guess and I have no data to backup my assumption